# Can we prove that $K_n$ is Hamiltonian for all $n\geq3$?

Tags: graph-theory

Can we prove that $K_n$ is Hamiltonian for all $n\geq 3$ ? I was unable to prove it. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: Take the $n$ vertices and take $C_n$,($n$ long circle), $K_n$ has $C_n$ as subgraph, so this will be good as a Hamilton-circle.

If you want a more solid approach, use [Dirac's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy.E2.80.93Chv.C3.A1tal_theorem): If a simple graph has $n$ vertices($n \ge 3$), and every vertex has at least $\frac{n}{2}$ degree, G will have a Hamilton-circle. In $K_n$, every degree is $n-1$, and $n-1 > \frac{n}{2}$, if $n \ge 3$.

Comment: Thank for your response....

Comment: Hope you understand it.

Comment: I put in a more solid approach too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I got it.......

Comment: @Atvin: Is Dirac's theorem a sufficient condition for a graph to be Hamiltonian?

Comment: Yeah, if it stands, it is Hamiltonian.